# jQuery convert one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element as below;

```
<div class="editableTxt" data-model-attr="myAttr" data-model-id="302">VALUE</div>
```

I want it to be converted to

```
<input class="editBox" data-model-attr="myAttr" data-model-id="302" value="VALUE" />
```

Is there a generic way to do the same?

Assume I am inside a callback & $(this) represents the div element..

Comment: Can you not amend the HTML?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$('.editableTxt').each(function () {
    var $input = $('<input/>').val($.trim(this.innerHTML));
    $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attr) {
        $input.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
    });
    $(this).replaceWith($input)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gc7Vg/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : assuming `$(this)` is `<div class="editableTxt" data-model-attr="myAttr" data-model-id="302">VALUE</div>`

```
$input = $('<input/>');
$input.attr('class',$(this).attr('class'));
$input.attr('data-model-attr',$(this).attr('data-model-attr'));
$input.attr('data-model-id',$(this).attr('data-model-id'));
$input.val($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('class', 'editBox').val('VALUE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).addClass("editBox").removeClass("editableTxt").attr("value", $(this).html()).html("");
```